# Is there a "brute-force" way to add a footer to a particular page?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, templates

I'm working with a complex thesis template that I don't fully understand (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis).  I've tried to modify it to make the abstract have arabic numbers, followed by a preliminary section in roman numerals, followed by the chapters in arabic numbers again.  However, the first page of the abstract has a page number, and not the successive pages.

Here is a snip of the abstract section of the .cls file:

```
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
\btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
%%   \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \bigskip
    {\large{Abstract} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\large \@title \par} % Thesis title
    \medskip
    {\normalsize by \\ \authornames \par} % Author name
    \bigskip
        {\normalsize fff\par} % Degree name
    \bigskip
        {\normalsize University of fff\par} % Degree name
    \bigskip
        {\normalsize Professors fff ch-chairs\par} % Degree name

        \bigskip
       \bigskip

  \end{center}
}
```

and here is the abstract section of the main .tex file

```
\mainmatter
\addtotoc{Abstract} % Add the "Abstract" page entry to the Contents

\abstract{\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics
Abstract text...

}

\clearpage % Start a new page
```

Sorry for no MWE, not sure that one would be feasible.  Any idea how I can ensure page numbers on all of the abstract pages, and not just the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\thispagestyle{plain}` sets a page number for just this page. Adding `\pagestyle{plain}` will set it for subsequent pages as well (indefinitely i.e. until you change it again).

```
\thispagestyle{plain}\pagestyle{plain}
```

Probably you need an adjustment later but it is impossible to tell without a more complete example.